# different ways of creating Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am used to the concept of classes and objects like in `java` or `c++`. In javascript the way objects are coded seems strange to me

```
var a = {property1:1, property2:100};
```

This looks like a map in `python`. I already understand that this can achieve most of what I expect of a object since I can store functions into variables. However I also saw that you can use

```
class testclass {
  constructor(property1, property2) {
     this.property1 = property1;
     this.property2 = property2;
  }
}
var a = new testclass(1,100);
```

to create objects. Now the question which arises is what is the difference to the following?

```
function testclass(property1, property2) {
    this.property1 = property1
    this.property2 = property2
}
var a = new testclass(1,100);
```

In my understanding a object is a instance of a class but in the first example it is more a map which is maybe a instance of a class but in this kind of view every object is a instance of the same class...

I hope somebody can enlighten me.

Comment: The main difference is 20 years of evolution ;-)

Comment: (almost) everything in Javascript is an object.

Comment: "instance of a class" -> instance of an object. JS doesn't have classes, only the class keyword.

Comment: JS classes are still classes, even if it's prototypal inheritance. Sure, they're different from classical inheritance, but it's still a class.